# Interpretation of $ \int_A f \ d\mu $ in case $\mu (A) = \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, intuition

Let $\mu$ be a measure and $f$ measurable and real-valued. If $\mu (A) < \infty$ then $\frac{1}{\mu (A)}  \int_A f \ d\mu $ (assuming the integral exists) is the $\mu$-average value of $f$.

Is there any other (except "area\volume") interpretation of $ \int_A f \ d\mu $ in case $\mu (A) = \infty$?

Comment: the only consistent definition coming to my mind would be $\lim_{\mu\left(A\right)\rightarrow \infty}\frac{\int_{A}f\mathrm{d}\mu}{\mu\left(A\right)}$. (if the limit exists, i think it might exist for $f\in L^{1}_{loc}$, but that is a guess.)

Answer (score 0):

The $\mu$-average $\left(\frac{1}{\mu (A)}  \int_A f \ d\mu \right)$ may exists even if $\mu(A)=\infty.$

Consider, as an example, $A=[1,\infty)$, $f(X)=\frac1x,$ and let $\mu$ the Lebesgue measure.

We may say that

$$\frac{1}{[1,\infty)}  \int_A f \ d\mu=_{\text{def}}\lim_{b\to\infty}\frac1{\lambda([1,b))}\int_1^b\frac1x \ dx=\lim_{b\to\infty}\frac{\ln(b)}{b-1}=0. $$